How to condition a bivariate Gaussian on two lines in $\mathbb R^2$ that are not parallel?
How to condition a bivariate Gaussian with mean $\mu$ and $\Sigma$ (e.g. $\sigma=\sigma^2I$) on two lines $\{(x,y):a_1x+b_1y+c_1=0\}\cup\{(x,y):a_2x+b_2y+c_2=0\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ that are not parallel to one another / that intersect?

maybe you can model it as a mixture of two degenerate gaussians? It's not immediately obvious to me why the fact that they are not parallel /that they intersect is salient; if that presents difficulties can you make them explicit?

Assuming $\Sigma$ is nonsingular, the two lines are almost surely disjoint, so how does this question really differ in nature from conditioning on a single line?
